# Why RJ11 Is Not Working With My Cable Tester?

Tags: phone, rj-45, cable-tester

This is the tester that i have:

[image]

It says that besides RJ45, BNC and USB it can test RJ11. The problem is that nothing happens when i test RJ11s in RJ45 input.

**[Here is the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=9vihK_3qoM0&hd=1)**

Somehow RJ11 worked in this video but not correctly in my opinion. It worked which is a rare case and should be taken as an exception.

I tried RJ11 with 2 contacts and 4 contacts as seen on **[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWCcr.jpg)**

Left - 4 contacts and right 2 contacts. I have tested both and tester does not do anything but in reality both cables work. Here is how RJ45/12/11 input looks like:

[image]

It has 8 lines exactly for LAN cable but manual mentions that RJ12 and RJ11 can both be tested as well.

Comment: I haven't looked at the video yet, I see you've made some effort to explain your predicament.  Just looking at your question, you shouldn't be testing RJ45 in the RJ11 input. You're supposed to test RJ45 in the RJ45 input, and RJ11 in the RJ11 input.

Comment: you have a funny one, i've seen one where the main part has an actual RJ11 socket on it next to the RJ45. and the detachable part has an RJ45 on one side and an RJ11 on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One I have lying around (and I don't use it 'cos it failed to detect a network cable was bad), but I still have it on the table here, it has 2 parts like yours, and is even the same model number as yours. NS-468.

On the one I have

The main part has an actual RJ11 socket on it next to the RJ45. It doesn't have USB and BNC.

and the detachable part has an RJ45 on one side and an RJ11 on the other.

It looks like your one is a variant of my one, and your one doesn't support RJ11.

My one supports RJ45 and RJ11 but not BNC and USB. And it's the same model as yours. NS-468 So  maybe has the same manual.

I got mine off ebay, I have no use for it since I found it not to detect a bad network cable, but at least it came in a nice soft case with a zip, and was cheap.

Here's a picture of this one from google images, it has RJ11 (see the smaller socket next to RJ45)
[image]

Don't be put off by label color. Looking at one next to me, happens to be black with an orange label. I have another which is grey with a blue-green colored label, but both are the same with RJ11 unlike yours.

See in the video, your one says RJ45+USB (on the label above the LED labelled 1).

My ones say RJ11+RJ45  Like that one in the pic included in this post.

My ones are also like yours to the extent that not only is it NS 468 it also says ZL 02 3 13103.9  Just has different interfaces/sockets to yours, and the labelling of RJ45+RJ11 that your doesn't have.

Comment: Does G light up along with the rest 1-to-8 lights? In manual it says it should but i have everything lighted up except G.

Comment: @Boris_yo I don't know 'cos I don't have a battery(that fits) to check.

Comment: OK I just found the manual. Though no battery. It looks like maybe G only lights up for Shielded. My ethernet cables and probably yours too, our  cat5 cables, are UTP (U=Unshielded).  So I suppose if you cut them open, then unlike a USB cable, these ethernet cables don't have a silver foil like wrapper inside around the conductors.   On one page it says "test of double twisted cables" and says 1 to G. On another page, it says that for UNSHIELDED lights go 1 and 2 to 7 and 8 i.e. 1 to 8 !

Comment: looks like B and G might be BNC and Shield or something. Also there's N-468 N-468B and N-468N each has the different ports on it. And there's ST-248 which yours might be, that has BNC so maybe that one is yours. Anyhow, not worth knowing this rubbish IMO 'cos the device didn't find my bad cable.

Answer (score 1):

bad news my friend, looks like you do not have an RJ11 port. You only have an RJ45 port.

You will notice that the head for the RJ11 does not quite fit properly in the RJ45. An RJ45 head is slightly larger than that of RJ11 and will not fit in the port at all.

Answer (score 1):

Make up a couple of RJ11-RJ45 adapters, and it should work just fine.

Comment: How to do that? Or where can i buy RJ45 to RJ11 converters?

Comment: If you have a crimper, the simplest is to cut a short RJ11 cable in half and crimp RJ45 ends on the cut ends.  Just be sure to get both halves wired the same way, ideally with the 4 wires on the 4 center pins of the RJ45.  But if you Google "rj11 rj45 adapter" you'll find about 100 options.